# Need some help iterating through an array and making conditional changes

Tags: ruby

I would like to generate an array, then walk through it multiple times, making changes to items in the array based on their state. I am having trouble getting the condition statements to work properly

```
lockers = Array.new(900, "Closed");

#walk through and change every other item to "closed" if it is "open", and 
"open" if it is "closed
(1...lockers.size).step(2).each { |i| 
if lockers[i] = "Open"
lockers[i] = "Closed";

elsif (lockers[i] = "Closed")
lockers[i] = "Open";
end

lockers.join };


#walk through and change every 3rd item to "closed" if it is "open", and 
"open" if it is "closed
(0...lockers.size).step(3).each { |i| 
if (lockers[i] = "Open")
lockers[i] = "Closed";

elsif (lockers[i] = "Closed")
lockers[i] = "Open";
end

lockers.join; };

#walk through and change every 4th item to "closed" if it is "open", and "open" if it is "closed
(0...lockers.size).step(4).each { |i| 
if (lockers[i] = "Open")
lockers[i] = "Closed";

elsif (lockers[i] = "Closed")
lockers[i] = "Open";
end

lockers.join; };
```

Doing the above results in the array being made properly with everything set to "Closed". After the first walk through, it fails to change any of the items to "Open".

If I change the conditional to "lockers[i] = "Open"", then obviously that works. But then the later conditionals also fail to pick up every item that it should be.

Comment: `if lockers[i] = "Open"` this is always `true`. Since variable assignment always is a true value. What you are using is `assingment` with `=` but from the context I guess you want to use `==` which is the `equal to` operator.

Comment: @DennyMueller variable assignment is not always a true value. `lockers[i]= false` results in false.

Comment: Oh jeez, you are right. I knew it was something simple. Thank you.

Comment: This problem would be a lot simpler if you used `true` and `false` so you can use `lockers[i] = !lockers[i]` with simple logical negation.

Comment: Note: Although `;` is valid syntax in Ruby, it's exclusively used as a separator for single-line statements that would have to be multi-line otherwise. It is not used as a statement terminator. None of these `;` in your code are necessary.

Comment: If you found any of the answers helpful, please consider [selecting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the one you found most helpful. (Yes, I know there is but one answer. :-))

Answer (score 1):

This is one way you could do that.

```
def flip(lockers, n)
  h = { "closed"=>"open", "open"=>"closed" }
  (0..lockers.size-1).step(n).each { |i| lockers[i] = h[lockers[i]] }
  lockers
end
```

```
lockers = 6.times.map { ["open", "closed"].sample }
  #=> ["open", "closed", "open", "closed", "closed", "open"]

flip(lockers, 2)
  #=> ["closed", "closed", "closed", "closed", "open", "open"]
lockers
  #=> ["closed", "closed", "closed", "closed", "open", "open"] 

lockers = ["open", "closed", "open", "closed", "closed", "open"] 
flip(lockers, 3) 
  #=> ["closed", "closed", "open", "open", "closed", "open"]

lockers = ["open", "closed", "open", "closed", "closed", "open"] 
flip(lockers, 4) 
  #=> ["closed", "closed", "open", "closed", "open", "open"]
```

The following is another way.

```
def flip(lockers, n)
  h = { "closed"=>"open", "open"=>"closed" }
  lockers.map!.with_index { |s,i| (i % n).zero? ? h[s] : s }
end
```

I've assumed that, by "every other item", the first to be flipped is the first element of the array. (Note that the last element of the array has index `lockers.size-1`, not `lockers.size`.)

I understand that you wish to modify the existing array, so that's what I've done. To return a new array and leave the original array unchanged (generally the preferred practice), simply replace `map!` with `map`.

See [Array#map!](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-map-21) and 
[Array#map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-map).

Comment: I was going to suggest `map!` but I did not see the `with_index` thing coming. Interesting angle.

Comment: This is all really helpful, thank you everyone. Clearly I've got a ways to go.